# How to reconnect AKPlayer and AKMixer after AudioKit.stop()

Tags: swift, audiokit

After calling `AudioKit.stop()`, and then subsequently calling `AudioKit.start()`, I'm unable to reconnect my `AKMixer`/`AKPlayer` to AudioKit. It appears that the engine starts successfully but no sound is produced when I call `player.play()`. I'm not quite sure what I'm missing. I've boiled it all down to a simple demo project and I've included the most important sections of code below.

**View controller**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    public let tickSound = MySound(url: "tick.wav")

    @IBAction func stopAudioKit(_ sender: Any) {
        try! AudioKit.stop()
        print("AudioKit stopped")
    }

    @IBAction func playSound(_ sender: Any) {
        tickSound.play()
    }
}
```

**Sound Object**

```
class MySound: NSObject {
    private static var mixer: AKMixer = AKMixer()

    private var player: AKPlayer?

    init(url: String) {
        super.init()
        if let file = try? AKAudioFile(readFileName: url) {
            self.player = AKPlayer(audioFile: file)
            self.player?.buffering = .always
            MySound.mixer.connect(input: self.player)
        }
    }

    func play() {
        if AudioKit.output !== MySound.mixer {
            AudioKit.output = MySound.mixer
        }

        if !AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
            do {
                try AudioKit.start()
            } catch {
                assert(false)
            }
        }

        if AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
            player?.play()
        } else {
            assert(false)
        }
    }

}
```

Github demo project: https://github.com/rednebmas/AudioKitDemo

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for providing the example project, it will help a lot to diagnose what's going on.  In general starting and stopping the engine is not preferred, so in the mean time, could you get by with an architecture where you just stop the nodes from processing?

Comment: @AureliusProchazka My app is background enabled so if I don't stop the engine, my app will stay alive indefinitely and run down the users' battery. I just checked, and only stopping the mixer does not prevent the Audio engine from continuing to run in the background (I can see CPU cycles in Instruments).

Right now I get around this issue by recreating all my sound objects after restarting the engine, but it's becoming a burden in my code base. I tried manually working with AVAudioEngine and had no problems playing audio nodes after starting/stopping the engine.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka after quite a bit of time messing with AVAudioEngine I've found that you must reconnect the player to the mixer after restarting the engine (you don't have to reconnect the mixer to the engine). _But_, AudioKit's `mixer.connect` method does not work, you must manually reconnect like so `AudioKit.engine.connect(player.playerNode, to: mixer.avAudioUnitOrNode, format: nil)`.

Comment: @SamB, I've been having related problems in trying to make dynamic connections in AudioKit, and have posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63865844/audiokit-problems-connecting-new-input-node-to-mixer. Any thoughts/ideas/help would be hugely appreciated.